# MSBuild Exec fail when UseCommandProcessor set to True

Tags: msbuild

I define a target to call an exec

```
<Target Name="BuildInstaller" >    
     <Exec Command="attrib -R /S /D $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Environment\Installer\ServicePlatform\*.*" />    
     <Exec Command="dir *.* /s" />  
</Target>
```

it Works perfectly

but if I add the UseCommandProcessor set to True

```
     <Target Name="BuildInstaller" >    
         <Exec Command="attrib -R /S /D $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Environment\Installer\ServicePlatform\*.*" />    
         <Exec Command="dir *.* /s" UseCommandProcessor="True"/>  
    </Target>
```

I got this:

```
c:\Dev>/Q /C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp63250fcf10714224b92eeeb09e25b6f5.exec.cmd
'/Q' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

why this happen? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks like a bug in MSBuild: it doesn't add `cmd.exe` in front of the string to execute. However in the [latest source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/blob/master/src/Utilities/ToolTask.cs#L1477) it looks like it's there so maybe it is fixed already. In any case it is probably best to file a bugreport at connect.microsoft.com. For now, if you really need a batch file (do you?) you'll have to do it manually

Comment: `Exec` task always uses lunches cmd.exe, because it wraps your command inside temporary .cmd fie. There is no need in specifying `UseCommandProcessor` for it.